# Python Pandas Replace Values with NAN from Tuple

Tags: python, pandas, tuples, nan, fillna

Got the Following Dataframe:

```
   A    B
 Temp1  1
 Temp2  2
 NaN    NaN
 NaN    4
```

Since the A nad B are correlated, I am able to create new column where I have calculated the nan value of A and B and form a tuple:

```
 A      B       C
Temp1   1   (1,Temp1)
Temp2   2   (2, Temp2)
NaN    NaN  (3, Temp3)
NaN     4   (4, Temp4)
```

Now I have to drop the column C and fill the Nan value corrosponding to the Columns.

Comment: Also accepting answer is wrong, because it set values, not replace `NaN` like mentioned in question.

Comment: @mishy per the thread in my answer, can you explain if my approach would work or not.

Comment: @David Erickson, this is the small part of my problem but yes, I need to check for Nan and then replace, I don't want to change the original values in the data frame with calculated one if the values are given.

Comment: @mishy thank you for clarifying, I have made a simple update to my answer that only focuses on the `NaN` values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) with select values in tuple by indexing with `str`, last remove `C` column:

```
#if values are not in tuples  
#df.C = df.C.str.strip('()').str.split(',').apply(tuple)

df.A = df.A.fillna(df.C.str[1]) 
df.B = df.B.fillna(df.C.str[0]) 
df = df.drop('C', axis=1)
print (df)
       A  B
0  Temp1  1
1  Temp2  2
2  Temp3  3
3  Temp4  4
```

Or create DataFrame from `C` with [`DataFrame.pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) for use and remove column, set new columns names and pass to [`DataFrame.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html):

```
#if values are not in tuples  
#df.C = df.C.str.strip('()').str.split(',').apply(tuple)

df[['A','B']] = df[['A','B']].fillna(pd.DataFrame(df.pop('C').tolist(), columns=['B','A']))
print (df)
       A  B
0  Temp1  1
1  Temp2  2
2  Temp3  3
3  Temp4  4
```